# How to specify initial window size for Windows 8.1 app running on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1, windows-10

Is it possible to set the default window size for a Windows 8.1 app running on Windows 10?

I know that this can be done for a UWS app using APIs introduced in Windows 10. However, converting the app to Windows 10 will take some time.

In the meantime, I would like to be able to release a quick fix which would ensure that current Windows 8.1 app launches with the correct size.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible given that Windows 8.1 did not expose any API to do the equivalent when the apps were all full-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection to call part of windows 10 sdk at runtime within your windows 8.1 app. 
Take a look at Thomas Nigro blog, he does that for the vlc winrt app.