# Remove the height limit of an app targeting Windows 8.1, but running on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10

My question sounds simple: is it possible to remove [the height limit of an app, if it is targeting Windows 8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01dgZ.png), but is also distributed to Windows 10 devices? Or is it my only choice just to upgrade project to target Windows 10, and distribute a separate package for it?

A related question:
[How to specify initial window size for Windows 8.1 app running on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089337/how-to-specify-initial-window-size-for-windows-8-1-app-running-on-windows-10)

..and an answer suggests "You could use reflection to call part of windows 10 sdk at runtime within your windows 8.1 app". Well, I have turned the whole Internet inside out, and I didn't find any normal explanation of this mystical method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you've mentioned is use reflection to call [`ApplicationView.SetPreferredMinSize` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize.aspx) at run time within Windows 8.1 app like following:

```cs
var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
var setPreferredMinSizeMethod = appView.GetType().GetRuntimeMethod("SetPreferredMinSize", new Type[] { typeof(Size) });

if (setPreferredMinSizeMethod != null)
{
    setPreferredMinSizeMethod.Invoke(appView, new object[] { new Size(300, 300) });
}
```

Using this approach, you can reset the preferred min size and remove the default 768 height limit.
[image]

But please note that on Windows 10, Windows 8.1 app's ApplicaitonView is mainly controlled by system. If not necessary, please do not use reflection to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! As soon as I will sit to my project next week, I will try this, and will tell you if I succeeded.

Comment: I did not mention, that my project is in Managed C++. I hope this still possible.
I also tried to use your solution in a sample C# project for Windows 8.1, but there is no such method "GetRuntimeMethod" definition in System.Type. Did you import something specific? Maybe you could attach an example project?

Comment: @serpaulius: Yeah, `GetRuntimeMethod` is in `System.Reflection` namespace. Please add `using System.Reflection;` in your C# code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!